# Adding Close confirmation to the interactivity quickstart

Tags: wpf, prism

The sample project for the interactivity quick start is provided by Microsoft as a lesson on handling Interactivity Requests.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921081(v=pandp.40).aspx

I'm trying to tie into the windows closing event to allow a confirmation that the user does indeed want to close. This is something I need to implement in my application and I'm using the quick start as a clean project to work out these details.  I added a few lines to the MainWindow code behind.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Added InteractionRequest
    public InteractionRequest<IConfirmation> CloseRequest { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Added the following 2 lines:
        CloseRequest = new InteractionRequest<IConfirmation>();
        Closing += OnWindowClosing;
    }

    // Added method
    private void OnWindowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseRequest
            .Raise
            (
                new Confirmation { Content = "Are you sure you want to close?", Title = "Confirmation" },
                c =>
                {
                    e.Cancel = !c.Confirmed;
                }
            );
    }
}
```

To the XAML I added the Interaction Trigger:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CloseRequest}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True"/>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I must still be missing something since It's not giving me the confirmation window.  It is hitting the OnWindowClosing method and event raising the interaction request event, but the application just immediately closes.

What is still missing from this effort to allow a confirmation dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that raising the event does not hold the current thread from proceeding and so the Window is closed immediately after raising the event.

Try this:

```
private bool confirmed;

private void OnWindowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!confirmed)
        {
        CloseRequest
            .Raise
            (
                new Confirmation { Content = "Are you sure you want to close?", Title = "Confirmation" },
                c =>
                {
                    this.confirmed = c.Confirmed;
                }
            );
            e.Cancel;
        }
    }
```